# Can I extract .7z file using System.IO.Comppression

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I know this is a short question but I just badly want to know if I can extract any kind of archive files like .7z .rar etc using System.IO.Compression in xamarin

Comment: Zip, Deflate, GZip support.... Missing are things like tar, 7z, LZMA, there is an open issue from 2016 on this: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/9657 Note: these are all supported via 3rd party or open source libraries.

Comment: Ohh nice thank you.